Error [RequestTokenManager] getToken() -> NETWORK_ERROR. App: com.android.vending, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/googleplay
tengo aquí una simple activity con 3 fragments en donde añado una barra de navegación para moverme entre ellos.
Me pide,no sé porque,trabajar con el compileSdk 35 y targetSDK 35
Al ejecutarlo me aparece el error del título entre otros,alguna idea?
No sé como resolverlo.
Como los fragments están vacío no los publicaré.
Este seria el código xml de ActivityMain:
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"/>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/home_graph"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Este el mainActivity.kt:
package com.example.tusentradasapp

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.example.tusentradasapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding=ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val bottomNavigationView= binding.bottomNavigationView
        val navController= findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment)


        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.listFilmsFragment,R.id.loginFragment,R.id.pruebasFragment))
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)


        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}

Gracias de antemano,saludos.
